# Confusing Nest function behavior

Tags: list-manipulation

Using V12. I don't understand this:

```
Nest[sin, x, 3]
```

gives

> `sin[sin[sin[x]]]`

and

```
Nest[Sin,1.2,3]`
```

gives

> `71933`

```
Table[Nest[Sin,x,3],{x,-6,6}]
```

gives

> ```
> {-Sin[Sin[Sin[6]]], -Sin[Sin[Sin[5]]], -Sin[Sin[Sin[4]]], 
>  -Sin[Sin[Sin[3]]], -Sin[Sin[Sin[2]]], -Sin[Sin[Sin[1]]], 0, 
>  Sin[Sin[Sin[1]]], Sin[Sin[Sin[2]]], Sin[Sin[Sin[3]]], 
>  Sin[Sin[Sin[4]]], Sin[Sin[Sin[5]]], Sin[Sin[Sin[6]]]}.
> ```

But

```
Table[Nest[Sin, x, 3],{x, -2Pi, Pi}]
```

gives

> ```
> {0, Sin[Sin[Sin[1]]], Sin[Sin[Sin[2]]], Sin[Sin[Sin[3]]], 
>  Sin[Sin[Sin[4]]], Sin[Sin[Sin[5]]], Sin[Sin[Sin[6]]], 
>  Sin[Sin[Sin[7]]], Sin[Sin[Sin[8]]], Sin[Sin[Sin[9]]], 
>  Sin[Sin[Sin[10]]], Sin[Sin[Sin[11]]], Sin[Sin[Sin[12]]]}
> ```

Isn't this supposed to be something like:

> ```
> {0, - Sin[Sin[Sin[**5.28**]]], ... Sin[Sin[Sin[6.28]]]=0}
> ```

Of note: the plot of the same seems to make sense:

```
Plot[Nest[Sin, x, 3],{x, -2Pi, 2Pi}]
```

[image: Plot]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The results are correct.  The `Table` expression iterates over values of `x` that range from `0 - 2π` to `9 - 2π`.  We can see this if we use `NestList`:

```
Table[NestList[Sin, x, 3], {x, -2 Pi, Pi}] // Column
```

[image: output screenshot]

The `-2π` terms drop out because they adjust the angles by a full circle turn, i.e. to no effect.  Since the remnant arguments to `Sin` are exact integers, *Mathematica* leaves the results in exact symbolic form.  If we wish to force them to be evaluated numerically, we can use `N`:

```
Table[N@Nest[Sin, x, 3], {x, -2 Pi, Pi}]
(* {0., 0.67843, 0.7097, 0.140189, -0.633911,
    -0.730172, -0.272311, 0.573469, 0.741749, 0.389926} *)
```

Should we wish to view the numeric values of `x` but leave the nested `Sin` expressions unevaluated, we can use `Inactive`:

```
Table[N@Nest[Inactive[Sin], x, 3], {x, -2 Pi, Pi}] // Column
```

[image: result screenshot]

... which can be subsequently activated:

```
Activate[%]
```

[image: result screenshot]

The small inaccuracy in the first result shows why *Mathematica* prefers to work in exact symbolic form.

We can verify the individual symbolic and numeric results to confirm that they are equivalent within the vagaries of inexact arithmetic.  For example, the second result for `1 - 2π`:

```
Sin[Sin[Sin[1 - 2π]]] // N
(* 0.678429 *)

Sin[Sin[Sin[1]]] // N
(* 0.678429 *)

1 - 2π // N
(* -5.28319 *)

Sin[Sin[Sin[-5.28319]]]
(* 0.678429 *)
```